# WPF Moving object by Grid.Row?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a question, how to move objects in WPF app by rows? My Xaml looks like this:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Some columns here!/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Some Rows here!/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="Button1"               
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4"
            Width="50" Height="50" 
            Content="Button1" 
            Foreground="White" 
            BorderThickness="0"  
            Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" 
            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
            Background="#FF085078"/>

        <Button x:Name="Button2"               
            Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4"
            Content="Button2" 
            Foreground="White" 
            BorderThickness="0"  
            Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" 
            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
            Background="#FF085078"/>

        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    x:Name="ActiveItem"/>
```

What i want to do, is when i show another window in Content Control I want to move "Button2" under the second view from Content Control. How to move items under the contrent control and when i close second view, the items goes back to their main places? How to bind Grid.Row in way to do what i want to? If it will help, im working with Caliburn.Micro Framework>

Thanks for your advices!

Comment: `Grid.SetRow(Button2, 3);` is not what you want?

Comment: you can also bind Grid.Row to a bindable property

Comment: @Clemens Yes, its exactly what i want!

Comment: @Bijan Can you explain how to bind SetRow properly? I bet i need to make method to moving objects and then in method to show ContentControl call that method to moving objects

Comment: If you want to move the Button when the ContentControl's Content is non-null, you may also use a Button Style with a DataTrigger as a pure XAML solution.

Comment: @Clemens could you provide an example of what u explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare a Button Style that sets the `Grid.Row` property value depending on whether the ContentControl's `Content` is null or not:

```
<Button Content="Button2" Grid.Column="4">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="3"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, ElementName=ActiveItem}"
                             Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="2"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

If there is already a Style assigned by

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource X}" .../>
```

remove it and write this:

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource X}">
            ...
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thats look pretty easy to use, thanks! But what to do when VS yelling to me, that "Style" proeprty is set more than once and i cant get to <Button.Style> body? Same history with "Content" value. I updated my button pattern in main post

Comment: You can only set a property once. Either via the attribute tag `<Control Prop="X"` or as a own node `<Control.Prop>`. Remove the one you don't need. @metadon789

Comment: I have another question, what if i want to have multiple Data Triggers like above? @Clemens

Answer (score 0):

First bind each `Grid.Row` to a bindable property.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Some columns here!/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Some Rows here!/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button x:Name="Button1"               
        Grid.Row="{Binding Button1Row}" Grid.Column="4"
        Width="50" Height="50" 
        Content="Button1" />

    <Button x:Name="Button2"               
        Grid.Row="{Binding Button2Row}" Grid.Column="4"
        Width="50" Height="50" 
        Content="Button2"/>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="{Binding ContentControlRow}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                x:Name="ActiveItem"/>
</Grid>
```

Now in your DataContext-bound object, you need to define these bindable properties.

Note that, in MVVM, row number may be considered as a **view** thing rather than a **ViewModel** thing. So first you need to decide which way you want to go.

1. You can add these bindable properties in **ViewModel** and modify them through a **command**.
2. You can add them directly to **view**'s code-behind (MyWindow.xaml.cs or MyUserControl.xaml.cs) and modify them through an **event handler**.

In the second case:

1. You may forget about binding and just use `Grid.SetRow(Button2, 3);` as Clemens suggested.
2. Or you can use binding with these modifications:

   - Set `x:Name` of the user control (or window) hosting the grid to *e.g. `MyUserControlRoot`.*
   - Add `ElementName` to the bindings. *e.g. `Grid.Row="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControlRoot, Path=Button1Row}"`*